# How to REGEX // in C? Single line comments

Tags: c, regex, compiler-construction, lexical-analysis

I used the following to get it to work partially:

```
        %{
        #define OR 2

        #define AND 3
        .........
        .........
        %}

        delim     [ \t]
        ws        {delim}*
        letter    [A-Za-z]
        digit     [0-9]
        comments  [/]+({letter}|{digit}|{delim})*

    %%

    {comments} {return(COMMENT);}
    ......................
    ......................    
    %%
int main()
{
    int tkn = 0;
    while (tkn = yylex())
     {
          switch (tkn)
          {

case COMMENT:
printf("GOT COMMENT");
          }
         }
}
```

This is working fine. The problem is that the regex obviously does not recognize special characters because `[/]+({letter}|{digit}|{delim})*` does not consider special characters. How to change the regex to accommodate more characters till end of line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couldn't you just use

```
[/]+.*
```

It will match some number of **/** and then anything till the end of line. Of course this will not cover comments like  **/* COMMENT */**.

Comment: it would also cover `21/7`, thats not expected.

Answer (score 2):

may be its late. But I find this more appropriate to use `\/[\/]+.*` This will cover double slash and more and then the rest of the text.

Following is the explanation from [regex101.com](http://regex101.com)

```
\/
```

matches the character `/` literally (case sensitive) Match a single character      present in the text

```
[\/]+
```

`+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `\/` matches the character `/` literally (case sensitive)
`.*` matches any character (except for line terminators)

Answer (score 1):

A single-line comment expression starting with '//' can be captured by the following regular expression.

```
\/\/[^\r\n]*
```

`\/\/` matches the double-slash
`[^\r\n]*` matches as many characters that are not carriage-return or line-feed as it can find.

However, the C language allows a single line comment to be extended to the next line when the last character in the line is a backslash (\). Therefore, you may want to use the following.

```
\/\/[^\r\n]*(?:(?<=\\)\r?\n[^\r\n]*)*
```

`\/\/` matches the double-slash
`[^\r\n]*` matches as many characters that are not carriage-return (\r) or line-feed (\n) as it can find
`(?:` start a non-capturing group
`(?<=\\)` assert that a backslash (\) immediately precedes the current position
`\r?\n` match the end of a line
`[^\r\n]*` matches as many characters that are not carriage-return (\r) or line-feed
`)*` complete the non-capturing group and let it repeat 0 or more times

Note that this method has problems. Depending on what you are doing, you may want to find and use a lexical scanner. A lexical scanner can avoid the following problems.

1. Scanning the text

   `/* Comment appears to have // a comment inside it */`

   will match

   `// a comment inside it */`
2. Scanning the text

   `char* a = "string appears to have // a comment";`

   will match

   `// a comment";`

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just write

```
"//"|"/*"    {return(COMMENT);}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Following regular expression works just fine for me.

```
\/\/.*
```